# How do I resolve " type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' " with ListView?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use the following code to make a list of menu items which I then want to display using ListView. This code populates the menuItemList correctly.

```
  Future<void> allMenuDetail(String orderID) async {
    _streamSubscriber =
        _dbRef.child('MenuItem/$orderID').onValue.listen((event) {
      if (event.snapshot.value != null) {
        var data = event.snapshot.value as Map;

        var price = data['price'];
        var itemName = data['itemName'];
        var desc = data['description'];
        var itemImg = data['img'];
        //  String itemID = data['id'];

        Map<String, dynamic> myMap = {
          'price': price,
          'itemName': itemName,
          'desc': desc,
          'img': itemImg,
          'itemID': itemID
        };
        List<dynamic> shortList = [myMap];
        menuItemList.addAll(shortList);
        setState(() {});
      } else {
      }
    });
  }
```

My issue is occurring in the ListView.

This is my code for the listView

```
          Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: menuItemList.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final item = menuItemList[index];//Error shows up here
              String price = item['price'];
              String itemName = item['itemName'];
              String desc = item['description'];
              String itemImg = item['img'];
              String itemID = item['itemID'];
          
              print('!');

              //   var cartPorducts = item['cartProducts'];
              return Container(
                  height: 95,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24)),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 10, 8, 10),
                  child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ItemPageState(
                                path: categoryPath,
                                itemName: itemName,
                                desc: desc,
                                price: 9,
                                itemImg: itemImg,
                                id: itemID)));
                        // }
                      },
                      child: Card(
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 10, 8, 10),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(24),
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              ClipRect(
                                  child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                widthFactor: 0.8,
                                child: Image(
                                  image: AssetImage(itemImg),
                                  height: 100,
                                  width: 150,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              )),
                              const SizedBox(width: 30),
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    itemName,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black, fontSize: 25),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'Price: R', //+ price.toString(),
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 30),
                            ]),
                      )));
            },
          ))
        ]),
```

I have done it this way in other parts of may code and it worked fine but for some reason it does not seem to work in this instance. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code for `menuItemList`?

Comment: I solved the issue. I had to change my variable in the list view from String to var which is how I had it in other places

Comment: @Stamp777 not change it to var, you need to convert it to string. if you just convert it to var later you will be have issue in displaying it in text widget.

Answer (score 1):

Inside Your `listView`, price is `int` but you assign it to `String` so change it to this:

```
String price = (item['price'] as int).toString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String price = item['price'].toString();
```